Why does the openMP barrier behave differently depending on the threads number?
This snippet of code that involves incorrect use of barrier by putting them in a conditional block that cannont be reached by all threads.
int main()
{
#pragma omp parallel num_threads(4)
    {
        std::cout << "Hello from thread " + std::to_string(omp_get_thread_num()) + "\n";
        if(omp_get_thread_num() == 0){
#pragma omp barrier
        }
        std::cout << "Goodbye from thread " + std::to_string(omp_get_thread_num()) + "\n";
    }
return 0;
}

Here's the output.
Hello from thread 0
Hello from thread 1
Hello from thread 3
Hello from thread 2
Goodbye from thread 2
Goodbye from thread 3
Goodbye from thread 1
Goodbye from thread 0
| //deadlock

This leads to the following output as where thread 0 is stuck on barrier while other threads pass through, leading a to deadlock. However, thread 0 should'nt have reached the second std::cout line and the deadlock occured at the line before that.
Now changing if(omp_get_thread_num() == 0) to if(omp_get_thread_num() == 1) gives the following output:
Hello from thread 0
Hello from thread 1
Hello from thread 2
Hello from thread 3
Goodbye from thread 0
Goodbye from thread 2
Goodbye from thread 3
Goodbye from thread 1

As expected thread 1 stops and waits for other process, but once the others threads are closed it continues its execution with no deadlock. I cannot find any explanation for this anywhere.
The program is compiled using  g++ -fopenmp  -Wall -std=c++17 fine.cpp

The barrier only says the threads may become active again, it does not control the order in which the OS wakes them up and schedules them (again). So the order in which you see the goodbye message may vary anyway

The behavior of your program is undefined. You cannot make any assumptions for the execution of a program with UB. Any execution pattern is valid. What actually happens for the gnu openmp implementation is that thread 1 is stuck in the implicit barrier at the end of the parallel region but released the first thread from that barrier. The other threads release thread 1 by reaching the implicit barrier. In your first example, the primary thread gets stuck in the implicit barrier, because the explicit barrier is matched with the implicit one from the other threads.

As you said, the code "involves incorrect use of barrier", so analysing the result makes no sense to me... The result is an Undefined Behaviour (i.e. basically anything can happen).
